# how can I prevent extra background operations when I change an state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

**Introducing Code**

I attempted to write an Exercising code by React which illustrates a bus and its seats. The seats that are reserved, are unselectable and red. The rest of the seats are selectable by clicking on them and choosing a gender at an opened popup. **You can see and try it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-chaum-lcr5iu).**

[image]

**The Problem**

Everything works well. But my problem is about performance. I know that when a State changes, that component will be rendered again. Of course, only changes will be passed to DOM. It's OK.

The problem starts here that in the background, the component codes and its children's codes are executed completely. Consider my bus has 24 seats and a seat is a component. Every time you click on seats, whether you choose a gender or not, you will see many logs in the console which means (at least I think it means) everything is executed again.

**My Request**

how can I prevent extra background operations And improve the structure to avoid them?

I have no particular insistence to use `usestate` if I can solve it in some way.

Comment: What method are you using to store state if you're not using `useState`? Are you using a state-management library?

Comment: Now, I am using `usestate`. But if it makes a problem here, I prefer to use another way. you can read my code. I gave you my link on question.

Comment: I think it should be solved by react Context, NOT TESTED

Comment: @Sodhisaab Thank you for your attention But if you know of a related article about it on the internet, please share it with me.

Comment: @Sodhisaab `useContext` is used to access the parent state in all children without sending it by `props`. I'm not sure it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior on a React component, if the state re-renders, all the children re-renders **if there is a change**. In your case, you are passing `OnSelectSeatHandler` as a prop to the `BusSeat` component, which is a function. Since javascript evaluates `() => {} === () => {}` to false, your react component will behave as if the prop changed on each render. So, the flow is: seat clicked -> component rendered -> children rendered.

### One Solution

We need to tell React that the BusSeat shouldn't re-render when BusBody re-renders. To achieve this we need two things: `memo` and `useCallback` from "react". These do not come without a tradeoff, there are plenty of good resources to read on learning when to use `memo`, `useMemo` and `useCallback`.

That being said, what I did is:

1. Wrap the `BusSeat` component to memo:

```
  import { memo } from "react";

  export default memo(function BusSeat(props) {
```

2. Wrap the `OnSelectHandler` to `useCallback`. For this, we need a clean dependency array so that function doesn't actually get re-rendered on each button click. Therefore, I removed the `seatClicked` and moved `GetItem` to the top of the react component so it doesn't get recreated:

```
 const OnSelectSeatHandler = useCallback(
   (e, number) => {
     var seat = GetItem(number, props.items);
     if (seat[0].IsEmpty) {
       setSeatClicked((prevSeat) => (prevSeat === null ? number : null));
       setXPos(e.target.offsetLeft);
       setYPos(e.target.offsetTop);
     } else if (seat[0].user) {
       props.items[seat[1]] = {
         ...seat[0],
         IsEmpty: true,
         user: false,
         type: ""
       };
       setSelectedSeatCount((prev) => prev - 1);
     }
   },
   [props.items]
 );
```

## Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-kepler-xcm5r5?file=/src/BusBody.js)

*Note: Try to avoid updating props.items as you do in `props.items[1] = ...`*

Comment: Thanks for your attention and time to my question.